# How does keras decide the type of kernel use?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Here is a typical example of a convolutional layer that is added using Keras

```
conv_model.add(Convolution2D(filters, kernel_size[0]
              , kernel_size[1], input_shape=(1, 28, 28)))
```

Here filters is basically the number of kernels that the layer has. My question is simple. How does Keras decide the type of kernel it has to put in say a Gaussian kernel ?
(Using TensorFlow backend)

Comment: The filters are initialized once given a kernel initializer, but then the values change, as the actual filter values are learned. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: You are trying to say that the filter values are first initialised randomly like the weights in a normal neural net and then learned as the epochs go on ?

Comment: Precisely, that is how it works.

Comment: I belive that OP got confused by the term "kernel" which has dozens of meanings in ML. The suggestion of "Gaussian kernel" looks like OP refers to kernels as dot products in Hilbert spaces (like in SVMs), is this correct understanding @Tanmay? If so, "kernel" in a convnet has nothing to do with this concept, it is just a "naming collision", in CNNs a "kernel" is a matrix that you convolve with your signal, which is (as Matias suggested) fully learnable, end-to-end, thus there is no kernel "type", in the sense it is always "linear".

Comment: Yes I was talking about the kernels we use to convolutional matrices. So the  matrix is randomly initialised and then learned as the epochs go on ?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly state that using `kernel_initializer`

```
# function signature, here you can specify the kernel using kernel_initializer
keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, strides=1,
                                  padding='valid', dilation_rate=1,
                                  activation=None, use_bias=True,
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',
                                  bias_initializer='zeros',
                                  kernel_regularizer=None,
                                  bias_regularizer=None,
                                  activity_regularizer=None,
                                  kernel_constraint=None,
                                  bias_constraint=None)
```